# Web Scraping Wikipedia With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm just trying to scrape the title of an input Wikipedia page but I get `Bad Title` after running

Here's the code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wiki = input('Enter the wiki:')

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{wiki}"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="firstHeading")
print(title.string)
```

I wanted to eventually summaries the whole page but cant seem to get past printing the title

Comment: Your assignment to *url* needs to be an f-string

Answer (score 0):

You will need to prefix your string with `f` for it to parse `{wiki}` correctly. You will probably also need to encode the URL to handle special characters correctly e.g. spaces. For example:

```
import urllib.parse        
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

wiki = input('Enter the wiki:')

url = f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{urllib.parse.quote(wiki)}"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="firstHeading")
print(title.string)
```